# Generic Oauth 2 Provider Azure (OAuth Connection Settings) BotFramework SDK V4

Tags: botframework, bots

I need to implement my own authentication in my bot. I'm using Botframework SDK V4 and C#. I configured a new connection setting in Azure using as a service provider "Generic Oauth 2" and the authorization URL is opening successfully but them, what should I do to send a response to the user? How the user knows he is logged in? I don't know if I have to send something to the redirect_url? I'm very new with this, appreciate any help.

Comment: You just want to send a message like "you are now logged in" or something similar? What channel(s) are you using? Are you using Node or C#?

Comment: Yes I need to send a message to the user after the authentication and store the access token. I'm testing with the bot framework emulator but I have configured Facebook. I'm using C#.

Comment: When I call the redirect_uri with code and state parameters I get "Bad Request" response, I don't know if I'm missing something or what is the correct flow?

Comment: DId you happen to start with one of our samples?

Comment: Yes I did, I'm using "18.bot-authentication" But I don't want a Google, Facebook, etc providers, I want my own Oauth2 provider, but I did not find any example of this.

Comment: You should not have to change hardly any code in the sample to get your OAuth provider to work. You should only need to put in your appID, app PW, and connection name into the sample.  Almost the whole flow will be handled by the framework.  Have you set up your connection in the Azure portal?  if not take a look at [this walkthrough](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp), it explains AAD but will apply to generic OAuth as well.

Comment: Thanks for the documentation. I think my configuration is ok in my bot and azure, but I really want to know what else should I have to do when my login emerges. Do I have to send a HTTP Get request to https://token.botframework.com/.auth/web/redirect?code=XXX&state=XXX? Or what Do I have to implement to send the access token to the bot?

Comment: Thats what I am trying to tell you :)  you do not need to do anything like that.  After plugging in your app id, app password, and connection name (into the sample code) the sample should just work. No extra code needed.  If your provider has been registered in the portal the framework takes care of all that for you.

Comment: [This line](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/9fa1b93342464741beae4b6e12c247c84fb00357/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/18.bot-authentication/AuthenticationBot.cs#L198) and [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/9fa1b93342464741beae4b6e12c247c84fb00357/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/18.bot-authentication/AuthenticationBot.cs#L237) get the `TokenResponse` the token is `tokenResponse.Token` like [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/9fa1b93342464741beae4b6e12c247c84fb00357/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/18.bot-authentication/AuthenticationBot.cs#L240)